# Angular operator :: - what does it do?

Tags: angularjs

Today I was looking at some angular code and was surprised to see this operator. Not sure what this operator does? Could somebody provide more information on the special operator :: ? I have neither encountered this operator before nor seen it in AngularJS docs.

> project-id="{{::vm.projectId}}"

Comment: that's the one time binding - http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using that syntax will save on resources by not spawning a watcher for the variable.

When you put a variable in a template using the double-curly syntax (`{{...}}`) Angular will generally spawn a `watcher` for that variable. This means that whenever changes are made to that variable in your Angular code the front-end will reflect that change.

Sometimes this over-eager watcher syntax isn't what you want, though. For instance, you may have a variable that you know will not change, or a variable that will change, but you don't want that change reflected immediately. This is why you will sometimes see the `{{::my-var}}` syntax, as it doesn't spawn a watcher.